# How to execute function onPressed() before rest of the widget loads in?

Tags: firebase, flutter, asynchronous, dart, flutter-onpressed

So I have an asynchronous function that i execute when i click on a day from calendar. If in databse there is stored information on that day i add the result to List tasks. This is that function

```
// This code is suppose to get all the taskNames of user on clicked day
  Future<void> getUserEvents() async {
    //We get Collection of 'userAssignments' from database
    final CollectionReference userAssignments =
        Firestore.instance.collection('userAssignments');

    //We get current logged in user
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

    //This is used to format a DateTime of selected day to String 'yyyy-MM-dd'
    var formater = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    String formatted = formater.format(_controller.selectedDay);

    //We get rid off a all the unneded data from list
    tasks.clear();

    //This is a query, We loop through entire collection and we look for a document
    // with email of logged in user and we look for a day that is
    // equal to selected formated day (variable formatted)

    userAssignments
        .where("userEmail", isEqualTo: user.email)
        .where("eventDayForCalendar", isEqualTo: formatted)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) => data.documents.forEach((doc) {

              // We get a taskName from that document and we add it to our local List tasks
              String taskName = doc["taskName"];

              tasks.add(taskName);
            }));
  }
```

And right here is the code for the widget. On the bottom of code ,Column is responsible for displaying a card for each element in List tasks.

```
//This is the class in which you can initialize widgets
class _CalendarPageState extends State<CalendarPage> {
  final DatabaseService _dbServices = DatabaseService();
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  //This List stores all found tasks while conducting a getUserEvents()
  List<String> tasks = new List<String>();

//Here is placed the code from above

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //This creates a box that sorrounds the calendar and makes it scrollable
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TableCalendar(
              events: _events,
              //Set the calendar controler parameter
              calendarController: _controller,
              //Set the starting day of the week to monday
              startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
              //Set default calendar format to week
              initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.week,
              onDaySelected: (day, events) async {

                //Here i call the function that executes query and 
                // stores results in list tasks
                await getUserEvents();
                setState(() {
                  _selectedEvents = events;
                });
              },
              //Start defining the calendar style
              calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                todayColor: Colors.green,
                selectedColor: Colors.blue,
              ),
              headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
                //Hide the formatter for week/month
                formatButtonShowsNext: false,
                formatButtonVisible: false,
                centerHeaderTitle: true,
              ),
            ),
            Column(
                children: tasks
                    .map((i) => new Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(i.toString()),
                          leading: Icon(Icons.assignment_turned_in),
                        )))
                    .toList())
          ],
        ),
      ),
   
    );
  }
```

[This is how it looks when function loads in before Column Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFGJ9.png)

[And this is how it looks on the same day if widget loads in before function is completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ67Y.png)

Is there maybe a widget that will pause code from executing below him or inside him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you add `setState((){ tasks =tasks; });` at the end of getUserEvents() the widget should rebuild.